# for loop assigning last result to variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make it so that whenever a user creates a game, the wager value that they set to their game is displayed on the screen next to the join button correlated to their game.

Here is what the UI looks like that I am trying to change:

[image]

And this is the database structure that these are being drawn from in firebase:

[image]

But as you can see, the wager value always resorts to the last wager node in the database. It does this, because the for loop that receives these values is going through every single wager value in the database, and assigning the value it gets to a variable. Here is the loop getting the wager values

```
    public void getWager(final WagerCallback wagerCallback) {
    FCGames.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                double wagerr = snapshot.child("wager").getValue(Double.class);
                String wagerD = Double.toString(wagerr);
                boolean wage = wagerD.endsWith("0");

                if(wage) {
                    wagerD = "$"+Double.toString(wagerr)+"0";
                } else
                    wagerD = "$"+Double.toString(wagerr);

                wages.add(wagerD);

                        wagerCallback.onCallback(wagerD);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}
```

I then set the textView value to wager in my RecyclerViewer class here:

```
        fcl.getWager(new FlipCoinLobby.WagerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String wager) {
                    holder.wager.setText(wager);
            }
        });
```

And I am stuck on how to get each wager value from the database and assigning it to the correlated interface. I have tried making a for loop that adds the wagers to a list, and then matches the indexes of the wagers and the list of nodes, but that didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pull all the data into some sort of local structure. Make a class for "player" with variables for the data then use it to do what ever you are doing. Not sure if that is a list/recycler view or not.

If you are just looking for value at a time, have another value to check like the name and when you have a match, grab the wager and use a break to exit the loop.